# Moving Drupal site from root on one server to subdirectory on another

Tags: drupal, broken-links

I'm moving a Drupal site from the root of one server to a subdirectory on another. The frontpage works fine, but all links are broken.

I've inherited a site that was located in the root. When I accessed the site site.com I came to the frontpage and everything worked just fine.

Now, I changed host and they told me to but the files in folder site.com/public_html. When I now visit the site.com I see the frontpage, but all links are broken. I'm guessing that I need to rewrite the urls somehow.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: you should then add the solution as an answer and mark this question as answerred, so that it doesn't show up on unanswered queue ;) PS. Yup, I arrived here doing so he he.

Comment: @versvs Sorry for that, added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to uncomment `RewriteBase /` and set `RewriteEngine` to "on" in .htaccess.